# Jupyter notebook ipywidgets not showing widgets Failed to display Jupyter Widget of type Label

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have written python notebook file, I install all ipywidgets using pip and getting below error

> Failed to display Jupyter Widget of type Label.
>
> If you're reading this message in the Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab
>   Notebook, it may mean that the widgets JavaScript is still loading. If
>   this message persists, it likely means that the widgets JavaScript
>   library is either not installed or not enabled. See the Jupyter
>   Widgets Documentation for setup instructions.

My code is as below,

```
    from ipywidgets import Button,VBox,HBox,Dropdown,Layout,Box,IntText,Text,FloatText
from IPython.display import display
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import HTML

label = widgets.Label('Select Product To Test').add_class(.para)
display(label)
```

Comment: For the first call only it happens.  If I manually run the script in jupyter notebook the widget state files are created.  For further invokes are running works fine.  Please help to resolve the issue for first run

Answer (score 0):

The `add_class()` function accepts a string as a parameter. So you ideally need to write

```
label = widgets.Label('Select Product To Test').add_class("para")
```

and then add any styling to your `.para` class.